# Foursquare API exposing secret in javascript

Tags: api, foursquare, secret-key

I want to integrate the foursquare API in my website but I'm not that familiar with API security so I want to make sure I'm doing it right.

I want to search for venues in an area like the documentation states:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search
  ?client_id=CLIENT_ID
  &client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET
  &v=20130815
  &ll=40.7,-74
  &query=sushi
```

Using javascript however, I don't feel comfortable that the client secret is exposed in my code like this, because if someone looks at my source they have the client_id and client_secret which makes it possible to authenticate themselves with my code:

https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth

Isn't that the same as, "hey look at my source code, my username = "someusername" and my password is "somepassword"?

Shouldn't the "client_secret" remain secret like it says? Or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Comment: Hey, did you find another way to hide the secret than the one described below (routing thru the API)?

Comment: No I didn't. Could not find a better/safer way than the one described below.

Comment: thx for the feedback, me neither :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're trying to access the Foursquare API using Javascript, which is executed on the client side, so yes, anybody using your website can, with a little bit of investigation, see the secret key that you're using, which is something that you definitely don't want to do.

The way to get around that is not to access the API using code that is executed on the client side. Whatever language you have building the website on the server side should be the code that accesses the API (using the auth credentials that you have set up) and then returns the results of the API call to the rest of the code.

Alternately, you can get users to authenticate with Foursquare and get an access token, which you can then use in user-specific API calls, and it won't matter if those are executed on the client side. I think this is the relevant page in the documentation for using that method: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#access

Comment: Thx, it seems the only solution indeed to get the data from my API, however, it is a lot slower this way instead of directly calling the API.